# SQL select from and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, the orders are `'VERIFIED'` or sometimes `'COMPLETED'` (`'COMPLETED'` means images were sent to the order, `'VERIFIED'` means the tech "verified" the images are correct for that patient).

I want to mark these studies `'READ'` which will keep the orders with the images on the server, but drop them off the list that the doctors and radiology tech see so their list isn't so cluttered.

Now, I am going into a table and one at a time `CTRL + V + DOWN ARROW` one at a time which is going to take a long time as there are thousands. 
I am `CTRL + V` the `Status` in the table from `'COMPLETED'` or `'VERIFIED'` to `'READ'`.

```
SELECT     StudyUID, StudyDate, StudyDesc, PatName, Status, StoragePath
FROM       Studies
WHERE     (Status = N'VERIFIED')
```

is just my query to see the table. 
I tried to search through posts but the replace or insert command I am scared to try because I learned once you change something in SQL there is no undo.

`Status` is the column data I need to change in mass, the data I want to replace under that column is `'VERIFIED'` to `'READ'`. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT     StudyUID, StudyDate, Accession, StudyDesc, PatName, Status, StoragePath
FROM         Studies
SELECT Replace(Status, 'VERIFIED', 'READ')
WHERE     (Status = N'VERIFIED')
```

Comment: Your concern about undo is valid. This is the exact reason why you want either a backup table or another backup pattern. I like a history table populated by trigger personally. If you want to see all the changes ever made, it's easy and if you ever need to revert back a bad update, you'll have the data.

Comment: When you have decided on which answer bests addresses your question, you need to click on the Check Mark next to the answer you want to show as accepted/.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an [`UPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) statement.

This should do it for you:

```
UPDATE Studies
SET Status = 'READ'
WHERE Status = 'VERIFIED'
```

Also, in terms of being able to "undo", there are two ways to do this.

One, you can use [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) and then none of the changes you make will be commited to the database untill you run [`COMMIT TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx).

Two, create a new database and copy the data from the table to want to backup to the new database. (I'm assuming that you can't do a backup/restore of the full database)

Comment: Wow... Just wow, first off I did not expect a response so fast. Second, that worked perfectly, you are awesome, thank you so much.

Comment: @GrahamBrandt Glad I could help!

Comment: @GrahamBrandt FYI  accepting an answer helps future users with similar problems

Answer (score 1):

@graham, You are correct that once you make a change to SQL you can't really easily go back and change it.

What it looks like you want to achieve is to change all the `status` that are either `completed` or `verified` to `Read`. This is achievable with an `UPDATE` statement.

Here is the SQL Statement you need to be able to achieve this:

```
UPDATE Studies
SET Status = 'READ'
WHERE Status in ('VERIFIED', 'COMPLETED')
```

The above statement must be used with caution. If you are sure that you want to change every instance in the entire database to `READ` then the above is all you need.

If you want to see what you are going to update before you do it, you can always do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM Studies
  WHERE Status in ('VERIFIED', 'COMPLETED')
```

If you have a db administrator that can backup the database that would be preferred so incase you did make a mistake you would be able to recover from it.

The note in a previous answer about `COMMIT` is not really relevant to what you are asking. It is meant for if you were making a series of updates, if one fails you should be able to roll back and don't do any updates. In your case you are just scared to make the update in the database. Updates that you are doing are truly irreversible unless you backed up your database. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Holy heck you are awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Using transactions offers some value even if you are only executing a single update, as long as you know the approximate size of the set you are working with. For example, if you are expecting to modify 300 rows and then SSMS says "3,000,000 row(s) affected" then you can be pretty sure you did something wrong, and would want to rollback. That said, if there is any uncertainty going in then one should really be testing with a select statement first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Studies Set Status = 'Read' 
where status = 'VERIFIED'
```

I would run `Select * from Studies where Status = 'VERIFIED'` first and save those records off to excel so you have a back up in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Why excel instead of a temp table? Or a new database?

Comment: If you use a temp table it will be gone once your session is over.  You could keep it in a new table if you wanted to.  I just prefer excel.  It is really a personal choice.  I like to cover my butt and keep a copy for a few days of what I updated or removed.

Comment: I suppose I should've been clearer with my terminology. What I meant was creating a new table with the same schema called `Studies_TEMP` and inserting all the data into that.

Comment: That is a good choice.  I don't have the ability to create tables where I work so it has never really been an option for me.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That makes sense.